# Using html:not when element has multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element with multiple class names and I cannot use an ID for this element. I want to trigger separate events when the element is clicked or when anything else is clicked. Right now when I click the element the event for which anything else is clicked is triggered due to multiple class-names. How can I solve this? And I plan on using JQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="stack a b c">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="stack a b c">
        2
    </div>    
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>      
<script>        
$('.a').click(function() {
  console.log("stack clicked");
});

$("html:not(.stack, .a, .b, .c)").click(function() {
  console.log("other clicked");
});

</script>    
<style>    
    .stack{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        border:1px solid black;    
    }    
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you looking for `$("html:not(.stack.a.b.c)")`?

Comment: event.stopPropagation()

Comment: @Naila My end goal is to make a dropdown appear when I click the button and make it disappear when click anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html:not(...` would select `html` tag which doesn't have any of those class. To listen  any inner element simply use `:not()` pseudo-class. Although use `event.stopPropagation` to prevent event bubbling up to the DOM tree.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>H</h1>
<div class="stack a b c">
  1
</div>
<div class="stack a b c">
  2
</div>


<script>
  $('.a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("stack clicked");
  });

  $(":not(.stack.a.b.c)").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("other clicked");
  });
</script>

<style>
```

Comment: Your snippet still triggers "other clicked" when click the stack

Comment: @user2557850 :  glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

- Exclude the html element when it has **any** of those classes

Using CSS selector:

```
$("html:not(.stack),html:not(.a),html:not(.b),html:not(.c)").click(function() {
  console.log("other clicked");
});
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$("html").not(".stack, .a, .b, .c").click(function() {
  console.log("other clicked");
});
```

---

- Exclude the html element when it has **all** of those classes

Using CSS selector, the bad thing about this one is you would have to try all combinations of classes in every order, so better to use jQuery:

```
$('html:not([class="stack a b c"])').click(function() {
  console.log("other clicked");
});
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$("html").not(".stack.a.b.c").click(function() {
  console.log("other clicked");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work clicking on a stack still triggers  console.log("other clicked");

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used based on the answers.

```
$('.a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("stack clicked");
});

$('html').click(function(e) {
    console.log("other clicked");
});
```